# What are the applicable processor for the ATmega32u4? And what are higher versions of ATmega32u4?

Tags: arduino-uno, keyboard, atmega32u4, arduino-uno-smd

Can arduino uno smd r3 version handle a Keyboard.h library?  it is not applicable for that arduino?

Comment: It is unclear, what you are asking.  The Arduino Uno cannot use the Keyboard library (unless you are hacking the USB to Serial chip). The Atmega32u4 has a native USB interface, thus it can use the Keyboard library, but the Uno only uses this chip as Serial to USB chip. The main chip is the Atmega328p, which doesn't have native USB

Comment: The ATMega32U4 is the ATMega32U4. There are no "higher versions" of it. What are you really asking?

Comment: Okay sir. But can arduino mega2560 use the keyboard library?

Comment: I am just clarifying if arduino uno can use keyboard library but now I know that it is not so, what type of arduino can you recommend on me sir for me to use the keyboard library?

Answer (score 1):

The Arduino Uno cannot use the `Keyboard` library. The microcontroller needs to have a native USB interface. The Uno uses the Atmega328p, which does not have one.

You can use the Arduino Micro or Arduino Leonardo for this.

---

For more experienced hackers: If you need to use the Uno, but still want to use extended USB capabilities (more than USB to Serial), it is possible to reprogram the Atmega32U4 on the Uno, which is only used as USB to Serial adapter chip, but of course has native USB capabilities and could create a HID/Keyboard input on the USB interface. Since that is not a task for beginners, it is not applicable for this question, but should be mentioned for future readers.